# Can't access a directory even with full permissions and ownership?

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm running into a weird issue. I have a directory, let's call it `dir`, which I (`user`) want to access. Having tried a few permission setups I can't get it to work, so I went to the extreme: change owner recursively to `user:user`, set permissions to 777. `ls -hal` now reports: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 94 Nov 16 10:35 dir`.
Yet, when I try `cd dir` I get `-bash: cd: dir: Permission denied`. The only way to access the folder seems to be to first `sudo su`, but I want to be able to give access to other users without sudo privileges, and it would be nice to be able to use the directory myself without using sudo powers.

What can I do to get into the directory?

EDIT: I accidentally did the `ls -hal` in the wrong directory so it shows `dir` as a symlink, but the actual directory `dir` links to has the exact same permissions, and I can't get into it the 'normal' (just use absolute path instead of symlink) way either. However, weirdly I can't even `ls -hal` in the parent dir of the directory I want to access: `ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied`

EDIT: Apparently I just needed to log out and in again and everything worked. I guess ownership doesn't immediatly change when logged in?

Comment: The `ls` output shows that `dir` is a symlink. What are the permissions on the directory that `dir` is pointing at? `ls -lLd dir` will show this.

Comment: I think we typed that at the exact same time :)

Comment: @PaulHaldane I pasted the wrong output; the permissions on the 'endpoint' of the link are exactly the same: owner is `user:user`, permissions set to 777

Comment: What are the perms of the parent directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working over SSH, logging out and in again fixes the problem.

Comment: Can you cite why this works?

Comment: @DaveM I have no idea, if you could post an answer including why it works I'd happily accept it

Answer (score 2):

The output suggests this is a symlink, so make sure the target directory has the correct permissions. Also, ensure that the specified user have the correct permissions to traverse all of the parent directories above this target directory.